# Extracting units of measurement from excel string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have some values in an excel string which contain various combination of characters alongwith unit of measurement. I want to extract only the units of measurement from the string. And if there is none, then it should return "0" or blanks. Following sample values:

- 4.875 in.
- 104°F
- 0.2mL
- 100 x 0.5, 1.5 and 2mL
- 50 x 5 x 49 mm

Could you please suggest a customized formula or VBA macro to help do it.

Comment: I would suggest creating a lookup list of UoM on another tab, and then using a string compare to see if your value+ UoM contains a value from the lookup list. If it does, 1; if it doesn't; 0.

Comment: The unit to be extracted is always the value tail, and previous symbol is always space or digit, is it?

Comment: Use VBA. Use RegEx object. Use search pattern `^.*[ \d](.*)$` and replace pattern `\1` [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/1EN9dz/1).

Comment: @Akina: No, there are some values which have the units somewhere in between too

Comment: If so you must build the criteria which allows to distinguish does some letters group is a unit or a common word (like `and` in 4th example line). Or at least show all possible variants of line values to be processed.

Comment: Actually it is a large data which comprises of various criteria. Some may have "and" or comma or some other long words or sentences

Comment: Common way: use some formula to extract a lot of units. Save them into separate table. Then select non-matched records, create separate formula for them. Repeat until all units distinguished and saved into units dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how comfortable you are with using KuTools, but I think this should help.

Try these Steps.....

1. Select the cell to split, and then click Kutools > Text > Split Cells, see screenshot :

[image]

2. In the Split Cells dialog box, select Split to Columns under the Type section, and then check Text and number from the Split by section, see screenshot:

[image]

3. And then click Ok button, select a cell to put the result in the popped out dialog box, see screenshot:

[image]

4. Then click OK button, and the text strings have been split into separated text and number columns as following screenshot shown:

[image]

Let me know if it works out..

Comment: is KuTools a free add in ?

Comment: for the first 30days it is

Comment: @Lokkii9,, above solution splits numbers from text but will this split measurement units ? Please add some examples using OP's data!!

Comment: Show does this tool may split digits from letters when no space between them. I.e. use OP's source strings, not some fake values.

Comment: @Rajesh S,, with excel there is no internal mechanism to identify units of measurements, so in case there is a VBA code that first defines "in", "mL" and other words as measurement units, and then analyses the data and tries spliting it, it will work,,,, or your solution to assume only last 2 characters are going to be the units, will be an answer.

Comment: @Lokkii9,, my suggested formula is nicely working,, but my question was,, what you have suggested ,,will this work the `KUTOOLS` !!

Comment: @Rajesh S,, yes pls, that is probably the only addon which has been reliable for me... but if in case there any new addons you know, pls do let us know.. would be really helpful..

Comment: @RajeshS: there is this convert formula in excel which has all the standard units of measurement. So I guess excel must have any mechanism? Just asking out of curiosity

Comment: @Irvin,, the `CONVERT` function only coverts value from Unit to Unit like,  `Meter` to `Inches` but you need is different,, Split the Unit from text in cell !

Comment: @RajeshS: Just gave an example that excel may have a mechanism since it has this default formula

Answer (score 1):

*This simple method will solve the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `J9`:

`=RIGHT(I9,(LEN(I9)-(LEN(I9)-2)))`

**N.B.**

- *Suggested method considers, `sapmle data posted by OP`.*

---

**Edited:**

*Since @Akina & OP raised one crucial issue that, unit of  measurement should be variable length therefore I've brought some sample data comprises variable length units as well standard patter of data entry (Space before units and not).*

**Sample 1:** Space before units.

[image]

- Formula in `K10:`

  ```
  =MAX(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(I10,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1)))*{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})+1
  ```
- Formula in `M10:`

  `=TRIM(RIGHT(I10,LEN(I10)-K10+1))`

---

**Sample 2:** No space before units.

[image]

**N.B.**

- *Method & Formula used with Sample 1 data ,solves this also.*
- *For neatness you may hide Helper Data.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: 1st OP's sample string will fail because of tail point...

Comment: @Akina,, I've posted the tested data by using the formula,, did you try this ?

Comment: @Akina,, if you are pointing `in.` then look it's not commonly used so you may remove `.` after `in` should read as `4.875 in`.

Comment: You have modified OP's source data. So the task you have solved is not OP's task. And I cannot find any guarantee that the unit length will always be 2 chars. For example, `1m` or `0.001L` will fail too.

Comment: @Akina,,, usually units are always  2 characters long like `Mt` for meter & what I've suggested may not be universal idea/method but what data has been show with OP, it solves it. And since `.` was not used in every row that's Y I've removed it.. because sometimes it's a TYPO too.

Comment: @RajeshS: agreeing with Akina, units are not always 2 characters. I mean it is fine if it identifies & compares the unit already there in excel. And yes it is not always tail

Comment: @Irvin,, what has been posted by you, the suggested formula solves it,, mostly units are 2 characters but yes few have single also K for Kelvin , A for Ampere ,, now my simple suggestion is please [Edit] your post and add some genuine data along with all possible combinations either is 1 Ch or 2 or more than 2 even , will help the community to find the correct Formula / Method .

Comment: @Irvin,, also make the text proper like space after data or I can say space before Unit or not for example Row 1 & 5 has space before the Unit but Row 2, 3 & 4 doesn't have ,, it also creates confusion !!

Comment: @Irvin,, now check the edited part of the post I've brought variable length units as well a perfect pattern also,, my 1 st method & formula considers exactly the data you have posted but newly show considers all (variable length units as well as space or no space before units) !!

Comment: @Akina,, now check the edited part of the post .

Comment: Excellent. The only addition - you may freely remove "Helper data" column usage by combining formulas and so using `=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1)))*{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})))` (for source value in A1).

Comment: LEN(I9)-(LEN(I9)-2) is just 2, so it's basically `=RIGHT(I9, 2)`, and only works if the unit contains 2 letters. What if there are mixed `m` and `km`, `cm`, `dam`...?

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote for the clever `MAX` array or downvote for the absolutely vacuous and unhelpful `RIGHT([string],2)` first 'attempt'

Comment: @Akina: Great! That formula works for most of the data though excluding the cluttered ones. Good attempt and thanks to everyone for their responses!

Comment: @Irvin,, glad to help you now you may accept it as answer as well up vote too ,,  and keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an Excel formula.

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/(MID(A1,seq,1)),seq)+1,99))
```

where `seq` is a **named formula** that refers to:

```
=ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))
```

The formula finds the last Number in the string, and returns the `TRIM`'d string after that last number

[image]